# How to find Entry and Exit events?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, eddystone

I have created an android an android application to detect both iBeacon and Eddystone. I tried getting the entry and exit time events. I created two hashmaps with mac address as key and current time as value. I then used comparator to compare both hashmap objects. If key is present already, I marked that beacon as last seen beacon. It doesn't fire any entry and exit events. Is there any other logic that will let me to find the entry and exit event?

Comment: Can you please show the code?  The technique you describe is similar to what the Android Beacon Library does to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 types of input events:

```
[KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener][1]
[Touch Events][2]
```